# Load n Record of Spreadsheet where parameter matches

Tags: excel

Working in Microsoft Excel, I have a spreadsheet with the equivalent of a shopping list, if the Quantity is greater than 0 then I wish to display the description on another sheet.

This is something that is quite simple using the INDEX function, however this only returns the first value that matches.

How should I re-factor the query below, to return the value of (n)

`=INDEX(Software!B23:Software!B34,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Software!A23:Software!A34<>0,0),0))`

Having assumed this to be an array, I mistaking thought I could call Array[n] for the location, however this has proven incorrect.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: can we use vba here? or you want direct formula?

Comment: Again VBA would be fine, it will still give the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't want to use `MATCH()`, you want to use the `SMALL()` and `IF()` functions together...

```
=INDEX(Software!$B$23:$B$34,SMALL(IF(Software!$A$23:$A$34>0,ROW(Software!$A$23:$A$34)),ROW(A1))-ROW(Software!$B$23)+1)
```

**Entered as an array formula**

Basically, what you're saying is:

Give me the row for which the data in Column A > 0 for the Kth smallest time
Now take that row and subtract from it the starting row of my dataset and give me back that entry from the array I have in column A.

And you could wrap the whole thing in an `IFERROR()` statement too to not have error values pop up.

One place to find more data about this would be [here](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/101167)

Hope that makes sense and does the trick!

Comment: Taking out the bracket issue above, I don't think this solves the issue as you are summing the whole range, not each index. =INDEX($B$23:$B$34,SMALL(IF($A$23:$A$34 > 0,"",ROW($A$23:$A$34)),1)-ROW($A$23:$A$34)+1) So if anything in the range is > 0 then the First record in the range would return.

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding your question... Aren't you saying whenever column A (quantity) > 0, give me the description from column B??

Comment: No, I am saying give me the nth column where the value is > 0, so on sheet 1 you have a list of 10 items 3 have a qty > 1. Sheet 2 should show the three items descriptions without any gaps.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I said... I'm not getting where mine isn't working.... Have you tried the function?

Comment: @Reallyethical, the more I'm trying to understand what you're asking for, the more confused I'm getting... Can you explain why my formula isn't working?

Comment: Thanks John, That was actually my fault I had not noticed you added ROW(A1) in there as the 'n' once I corrected for this everything works like a dream. I will be awarding the 50 point bounty in 23 hours to say thanks.

Comment: Just glad it worked, man!! I was getting quite confused why it wouldn't :)

Comment: Your not the only one! Thanks again for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful (dont know exactly this is what u want)

```
Sub test_index()
Dim ii As Integer, jj As Integer
ii = 23
jj = 24
With ActiveSheet
For ii = 23 To 34

Cells(ii, 12).Formula = "=INDEX(Software!B" & ii & ":Software!B" & ii & _
",MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Software!A" & ii & ":Software!A" & ii & ",0,0),0))"

Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Zat, not sure this helps either, this would basically allow me to exclude x, but would not give me pos 2 pos 3 etc that match the criteria (Unless I am missing something).

Comment: Hi, tried to insert formula for each cell in column N for example. If A column's data > 0 for each of 23 to 34 row, then column N cell will show B column's data otherwise show #N/A

Comment: That's not quite the problem, The issue is taking a large list in sheet 1 and only displaying the results (without empty lines) in sheet 2 where QTY > 0. Does that make sense?

Comment: after getting the result, rows with #N/A in column N can be deleted.